# Which is better? "Of or "from" this background?

Tags: word-choice

I want to know which preposition is better for the two sentences provided. I've perused definitions available online for both prepositions. As far as I can tell, both indicate relationship, which sometimes is one of origin. I get the sense, from example sentences, "from" is stronger than "of," at least in terms of origin, meaning if one were said to be ***from*** a country, it would likely mean they were born and raised in that country, whereas if one were said to be ***of*** a country, it could mean they have ancestry from that country.

1. There are people of/from many backgrounds in the world.
2. I work with people of/from many backgrounds.

Assuming the analysis I gave is correct, which preposition is better would depend on context that I did not provide for either of the above sentences.

Maybe "from many backgrounds" puts emphasis on origin while "of many backgrounds" on experience. Thoughts? If my thought process is flawed, please explain why.

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Please add more detail to explain which you think is better, and why, and what research you might have done to figure it out.  Otherwise the question will be closed as "proofreading".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I hope my edits are sufficient.